# How can I diagnose galvanic corrosion on a water pipe?

Tags: hot-water, galvanic-corrosion

I have a newly installed indirect hot water heater and two of the pipes are showing significant amounts of corrosion.

Given that the installation is only 3 months old, I suspect that there may be [galvanic corrosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion) involved. How can I test this and see if electricity is getting into the piping system and causing galvanic corrosion?

Comment: Check the anode inside your thank, in your case I suggest you to get an electronic one: it never cunsumes itself and prevent corrosion

Comment: Picture of the connections would help.

Comment: Galvanic corrosion isn't the result of external electricity getting into the system. Instead, it's a phenomenon that happens simply because two dissimilar metals are touching one another. A small voltage is produced right there at the joint; it's a lot like a battery. The severity varies depending on which metals are present.

Comment: If you see corrosion on the surface of the pipe ,it sounds more like small water leaks.

Comment: As @GregHill implies, if you have iron pipe meeting copper, that would cause galvanic corrosion -- though most would be *inside*, where you're unlikely to see it.

Comment: Please post a picture or two. It will be easier for us to propose a solution if we can see what's going on, etc.